# TSQL generate months based on start and end date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I have two variables `start` and `end` containing date values, e.g. `2018-05-01` and `2019-02-28`. I want to create a table that contains each month in between. The resulting table should look as follows.

```
Month   Year
5       2018
6       2018
7       2018
8       2018
9       2018
10      2018
11      2018
12      2018
01      2019
02      2019
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n, @start) FROM nums WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, @start, @end)`, with `nums` a suitable numbers table (some folks prefer a CTE for this; scour SO for questions on how to make one). I may be off by one, season with salt and pepper to taste to unpack the resulting `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a table function I use in MS-SQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSequencedMonthSplit](@StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME)
RETURNS @Results TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) 
    , YearValue INT 
    , MonthValue INT 
    , MonthName NVARCHAR(50) 

)
AS

BEGIN 



IF @StartDate IS NULL OR @EndDate IS NULL 
BEGIN 
    /*GET THE CURRENT CALENDAR YEAR*/
    SELECT 
        @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(year(getdate()),1,1)
        ,@EndDate = DATEFROMPARTS(year(getdate()),12,31)
END 



WHILE @StartDate < @EndDate 
BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO @Results (YearValue, MonthValue, MonthName) 
     SELECT 
        DATEPART(year, @StartDate)
        , DATEPART(month, @StartDate) 
        , DATENAME(month,@StartDate) 




    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(month, 1, @StartDate) 
END 


    RETURN  


END
```

then calling something like this:

```
select 
    MonthValue AS [Month]
  , YearValue  as [Year]
from 
    dbo.GetSequencedMonthSplit(@StartDate,@EndDate)
```

should give you something you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen Mostert's solution in your comments is the best possible way to go. David's solution will get you what you are looking for but his function is a `Multi-statement` inline table valued function, you want and `inline` table valued function [for the reasons outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805659/set-based-plan-runs-slower-than-scalar-valued-function-with-many-conditions/50806675#50806675). Even if though you are only dealing with a small handful of rows, Multi-statement can poison the performance of queries that use call them.

To create an `inline` table valued function (iTVF) you just need to understand how [tally tables](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) work. Doing so will change your career. The iTVF version of what you are looking for looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MonthYearRange (@startdate DATE, @enddate DATE)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
WITH L1   AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) x(N)),
iTally(N) AS
( SELECT 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH,@startdate,@enddate)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
  FROM L1 a CROSS JOIN L1 b CROSS JOIN L1 c)
SELECT [Month] = MONTH(d.dt),
       [Year]  = YEAR(d.dt)
FROM iTally i
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (DATEADD(MONTH,i.N,@startdate))) d(dt);
```

**This query:**

```
DECLARE @startdate DATE = '2018-05-01',
        @enddate   DATE = '2019-02-28';
```

**Returns:**

```
Month       Year
----------- -----------
5           2018
6           2018
7           2018
8           2018
9           2018
10          2018
11          2018
12          2018
1           2019
2           2019
```